# How to use Bind Variables in Informix Procedure

Tags: informix

I am trying to use Bind Variable for Informix Procedure.
Can someone guide me how to use for the below procedure?
                                                                           CREATE PROCEDURE neura_omega_stg.grn_payment_mode_update(vv_material_document_id Varchar(20),vv_payment_mode Varchar(10))

UPDATE goods_receive_header_tbl SET payment_mode=vv_payment_mode WHERE 
material_document_id=vv_material_document_id;

END PROCEDURE;

Answer (score 1):

If you use JVM language like Java, or Jython which can use Informix JDBC driver then you can use CallableStatement:

```
proc = db.prepareCall("{ call neura_omega_stg.grn_payment_mode_update(?, ?) }")
proc.setString(1, "10")
proc.setString(2, "20")
proc.execute();
```

In JDBC/ODBC you can use Prepared Statement:

```
pstm = db.createStatement("EXECUTE PROCEDURE neura_omega_stg.grn_payment_mode_update(?, ?)")
pstm.setString(1, "10")
pstm.setString(2, "20")
pstm.execute()
```

Comment: I am not working in Java. I want for Informix Database. (Data Studio).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably in Data Studio SQL Editor you would execute something like:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE neura_omega_stg.grn_payment_mode_update("One", "Two");
```